# defaultdict changes get reflected in list

Tags: python, defaultdict

i was just trying defaultdict and i am not able to understand as to why changing defaultdict (d[1]=2) causes change in the list v ,although appending has been done before the change in value. please help..

```
>>> d=defaultdict(int)
>>> d[1]=1
>>> d[2]=3
>>> v=[]
>>> v.append(d)
>>> v.append(d)
>>> v
[defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {1: 1, 2: 3}), defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {1: 1, 2: 3})]
>>> d[1]=2
>>> v
[defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {1: 2, 2: 3}), defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {1: 2, 2: 3})]
>>
```

Comment: Because they are the same object.

Comment: Because `d` is a _reference_, stored twice in your list.

Comment: how do i change the code so that it does not refer..

Comment: @thestalker Copy the object, e.g `v.append(defaultdict(int, d))` or `v.append(d.copy())` or `v.append(copy(d))` (see [`copy.copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.copy))

Comment: Thank you..this worked like a charm.. sorry for foolishness

Comment: @thestalker I guess, `d.copy()` is the most natural way for dicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one can change one copy without changing the other.

Which means that you should append a [shallow copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Shallow_copy) of `d` to your list:

```
v.append(d.copy())
```